# What does the color coding and normalized values in confusion matrix actually specify?

Tags: machine-learning, visualization, confusion-matrix

I am unable to infer anything about the model from the following confusion matrix. What is the color coding actually specifying?

For example, when predicted label is 1 and true label is 1, the value in the matrix at that point is `0.20`. Does that mean its accuracy? Does it mean that the model is only able to predict 1 only 20% of times when the label is actually 1?

[image]

PS: [SO URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQNcd.png) for a more clear image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `element_ab` shows the probability of predicting `label a` (horizontal axis) when the true label is `b` (vertical axis)
For example, when the true label is 0, it will be predicted as label 2 with the probability of 0.14

The color intensity indicates the probability of each element in a row

Comment: Okay, so the model is not good at all? For `true = pred` , probabilities are close to ~0.2

Comment: Yes, it is not good at all. Most of the data is predicted as label 1, label 2, and also label 3.

Comment: But it gives a test accuracy of 85%. What do I infer from that?

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use to create colors on confusion matrix.

```py
#Create Confusion matrix

def plot_confusion_matrix(cm, classes,
                          normalize=False,
                          title='Confusion matrix',
                          cmap=plt.cm.Purples):
    plt.imshow(cm, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)
    plt.title(title)
    plt.colorbar()
    tick_marks = np.arange(len(classes))
    plt.xticks(tick_marks, classes, rotation=45)
    plt.yticks(tick_marks, classes)

    if normalize:
        cm = cm.astype('float') / cm.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
        print("Normalized confusion matrix")
    else:
        print('Confusion matrix, without normalization')

    thresh = cm.max() / 3.
    for i, j in itertools.product(range(cm.shape[0]), range(cm.shape[1])):
        plt.text(j, i, cm[i, j],
                 horizontalalignment="center",
                 color="white" if cm[i, j] > thresh else "black")

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.ylabel('True label')
    plt.xlabel('Predicted label')
```